# How can I read a folium map html back to a folium map object in python?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, folium

I am working on a flask app as the following two steps:

1. Create a map by folium, save it as html file
2. Make some change to the map based on some input, and save the html again.

So my question is, as I already have the html from step 1, is it possible to read the html back to a folium map object, so I can make some change on it?

Any comment/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.